# what to change to android project after renaming?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have renamed my project and changed all aspects of it in the manifest and the code/packages to reflect the new name.  When I launch the program in the emulator, and make a selection that hits an intent its asking me if I want to open com.xxxxx.oldname or com.xxxxx.newname for this action?

Any ideas on what to check next?

Thanks

Comment: Did you just rename or refactor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you changed the package name, the new version didn't replace the old version.  Both are installed in the emulator.

Go to Settings -> Application Manager and uninstall the old version.

Comment: Thanks@!  I didn't even realize it was still on there!

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse, if you right click on your project then click refactor and rename it should take care of all of your references and resources. Hope this helps